# body onload event after click on link

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have link on my page test.php page.

```
  <a href="demo.php">click</a> <!-- test.php page -->
```

I want to call function on body onload event on demo.php page everytime but only when click on link above then it would not be called on page refresh.

```
 <body onLoad="JavaScript:event(1,product,100);">  <!-- demo.php page -->
```

Comment: what do you mean by pagre refresh?

Comment: i mean it should be called every time when user come from test.php page by click on link.then it should not be called on demo.php page reload.

Comment: You can do it simply by passing querystring. Just check if querystring is set and add `onLoad` attribute on body tag !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using hashtags in the URL, your link HTML:

```
<a href="demo.php#noCall">click</a>
```

The demo.php javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("#noCall") == -1) { //Does the hashtag NOT exist in the URL?
        alert("Event called when link is not clicked"); //Event called
        window.location.hash = ''; //Remove noCall from the hash for page-reload
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: thanx dillen but this is function is also called on page reload. and i need to call onload function when user come by click on the link.when user go back to test.php page and clicked again it would be called no matter how many times user come from link?

Comment: I think it's the way you want now.

Comment: @Dillen i use ur code:<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (document.location.href.indexOf("#noCall") == -1) { //Does the hashtag NOT exist in the URL?
        alert("Event called when link is not clicked"); //Event called
        document.location.href = document.location.href.split("#noCall")['0'] + "#"; //Remove noCall from the hash for page-reload
    }
 else
 {
     alert('test'); 
 }
};
</script> but when i come by click as well reload the page every time test is alert.

Comment: Thanx Dillen it is resolve.little modification in ur script.<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("#noCall") == -1) { //Does the hashtag NOT exist in the URL?
        alert("Event called when link is not clicked"); //Event called
    }
 else
 {

  window.location.hash = '';
 }
};
</script>

Answer (score 0):

add a variable like `var first_time = true;`, then in your function before doing anything first check if it is first time or not: `if (first_time == false) return false;` After running the function for the first time set the `first_time` to `false`.

**Correction**

The above solution will not work as expected in the question. The problem happens when you refresh the page. I'm not deleting this answer as it could help some other people to see the differences between working solutions and this one.

Comment: @DillenMeijboom Oh yeah, thanks for the correction, I didn't understand the question well, thanks for the comment.